# SSH agent forwarding to Docker Alpine container from Mac OS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, macos-sierra, alpine-linux, ssh-agent

Okay so for several projects I need to access my private repositories, so I'd like to forward the host's SSH Agent to the container to allow retrieving from these private repositories. Eventually I would like to implement this in docker-compose.

I've found a lot of answers and solutions pointing to something like this:

```
docker run --rm -t -i \
-v $SSH_AUTH_SOCK:/ssh-agent \
-e SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/ssh-agent \
alpine:3.6 sh
```

But when I run `ssh-add -l` inside there (after making sure `openssh` is installed)

I get the following error:

> Error connecting to agent: Connection refused

Also tried this within my docker compose setup but it doesn't seem to work like it should.
Due to most posts and solutions being several years old I hope someone can help me with accurate up-to-date info.

Answer (score 13):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/410#issuecomment-577064671) you can forward your macOS ssh-agent to your docker container by adding `-v /run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock:/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock"` options to your `docker run` command, e.g.

```sh
docker run --rm -it \
-v /run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock:/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock \
-e SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock" \
docker_image
```

Comment: Can anyone confirm that this works on macOS? I tried it and it doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: It didn't work for me, but this worked: https://github.com/nardeas/ssh-agent

Comment: It worked for me on macOS 13.6 with M2 Silicon, using Docker Desktop 4.24.2 (124339). There was NO path named /run/... on my local machine. These values are somehow replaced by Docker Desktop I guess?

Comment: It has worked for me too.

Docker deskop version 4.26.1. Apple M1 chip, macOS version 13.4.1.

Though no path is named `/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock`.

Answer (score 8):

1. Add keys to the launchd managed ssh-agent:

```sh
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=`launchctl getenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK` ssh-add
```

2. Forward the launchd managed ssh-agent to docker container:

```sh
docker run --rm -it \
-v /run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock:/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock:ro \
-e SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock" \
image ssh hosts
```

The mount option and SSH_AUTH_SOCK value in container are all magic constants, do not change them.

3. `launchctl getenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK` may output empty string on iTerm2 3.2+ due to the [bug](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/7654). The work around is one of:

- A [portable way](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/issues/78#issuecomment-899209930) for newer OS (>=10.13 i.e. macOS High Sierra) is `launchctl asuser $UID launchctl getenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, or
- For older OS, in iTerm2 > Prefs > Advanced, turn on "Enable multi-server daemon", or
- For older OS, in iTerm2 > Prefs > Advanced, turn off "Allow sessions to survive logging out and back in".

NOTE: if the `launchctl` problem cannot work round, there is another way to forwarding ssh agent via [stdio tunnel](https://github.com/payfazz/stdiotunnel#example-forwarding-ssh-agent-socket-to-container-via-docker-exec).

Comment: Thanks for leaving an answer to this question. Can you share your version of your operating system and which docker software and version you are running on it?

Comment: OS: MacOS 11.0.1, Docker: 20.10.0

Comment: Thanks. Is this docker for mac or are you running it with a different virtual machine?

Comment: Docker for Mac 3.0.0

Comment: The portable solution works great for me without needing to fiddle with iTerm! Great answer!

Comment: ls: cannot access '/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock': No such file or directory. macOS 14.1.2

Comment: @xpt '/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock' is a path in virtual machine of docker desktop, not the host os. so you cannot `ls` this path in the host os shell. just mount this path, the docker is finally run in the virtual machine then mount the collect pipeline into the result container.

Answer (score 7):

You can mount files, but not sockets - sharing sockets between MacOS through the hypervisor into docker containers is something that isn't supported yet. Various bug reports and acknowledgements exist, and some day it should work.

So in the meantime, you need to have something that forwards network traffic between the container and MacOS. One of the solutions that people point out is [docker-ssh-agent-forward](https://github.com/avsm/docker-ssh-agent-forward).

A different solution would be to run ssh-agent in a container and to access that from MacOS and the other containers - it's probably a bit more invasive but works. A solution is [docker-ssh-agent](https://github.com/nardeas/docker-ssh-agent).

Comment: Another solution would be to use ngrok: https://ngrok.com/ You can run it from within the container using `ngrok tcp 22`, and it will generate/expose a public FQDN that you can use to connect directly to the container.

Comment: the posted docker-ssh-agent-forward has not been updated for over 7 years now. If you, like me, just search for a working solution, you can try https://github.com/uber-common/docker-ssh-agent-forward. It's a fork of this one and worked right out of the box for me.